# Hover over help in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the easiest method in bootstrap for showing a small amount of text when you hover over another piece of text ??
Ive found solutions using jquery, css but wondered what the simpliest method is.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A simple example would have

`<span class="has-hover" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">Hover over me</span>`

in your HTML and

`$(".has-hover").tooltip({placement: "bottom"});`

in your js ([example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj8LV/))

Bootstrap tooltips are explained in detail at http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML "title" attribute

```
<div>
     Put your mouse on me
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div title = "you found me!">
     Put your mouse on me
</div>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)